# Why I get error missing right parenthesis ORA-00907

Tags: sql, oracle

I am stuck in one problem and I have no idea where did I made mistake.
Since I check everything and every solution but I can not see what I made wrong.

```
SELECT
    o.OrderID,
    o.Order_date,
    o.status,
    o.OrderAcceptanceCommentsSaved,
    o.OrderFileAttachment, 
    o.HasErrors,
    o.ErrorsResolved,
    (SELECT ou.Status FROM order_unload ou WHERE ou.OrderID = o.OrderID
     AND rownum <= 1 ORDER BY ou.Id DESC) AS UnloadStatus
FROM
    orders o
WHERE
    ProjectID = 141
ORDER BY ou.Id DESC;
```

The problem here is second `SELECT`

```
(SELECT ou.Status FROM order_unload ou WHERE ou.OrderID = o.OrderID
   AND rownum <= 1 ORDER BY ou.Id DESC) AS UnloadStatus)
```

However, when I want to execute only second SELECT I also get error

```
o.OrderID invalid identifier
```

Can someone guide me and tell me where I made mistake? What is wrong with this query?

Comment: Try replacing `and rownum <= 1 order by ou.id desc` with `order by ou.id desc limit 1`? Might be an Oracle thing I'm not aware of though. Syntax looks sane otherwise.

Comment: LIMIT 1 is MySQL function as I know not Oracle SQL

Comment: OK, my bad then. Your second snippet shows a closing parenthesis at the very end, that isn't present on the first snippet, is that a typo in the question?

Comment: First snippet is execute correctly, only problem is second SELECT which throw error. 
Even when I execute separetly I get error

Comment: here is no alias `ou` in your (main) query, so you can't use `order by ou.id` on the last line

Comment: Yeah, you can't execute the inner query alone as is, because it relies on `o.OrderID` (`o` being the alias of the outer table).

Comment: The second select has one open parenthesis, but two close parentheses. Is that intended?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, I see error. When I remove `order by ou.id` but I need order by

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several problems:

1. The `ORDER BY` clause is not allowed in a correlated sub-query so the SQL engine expects the query to end before the `ORDER BY` and there to be a closing brace at that point. Remove the `ORDER BY` clause in the inner select and that error would go away (and you would get a different error).
2. `ROWNUM` is applied **before** the `ORDER BY` is evaluated so, even if the query was syntactically valid, it would not do what you wanted as you would get a random row (the first the SQL engine happens to read) which would be given a `ROWNUM` of 1 and then the rest of the rows discarded and then that single (random) row would be ordered. You want to order first and then get the first row.
3. You are using `ou.id` to order the outer query but the `ou` alias is not visible in that outer select.

You can use:

```sql
SELECT o.OrderID,
       o.Order_date,
       o.status,
       o.OrderAcceptanceCommentsSaved,
       o.OrderFileAttachment, 
       o.HasErrors,
       o.ErrorsResolved,
       ou.status AS UnloadStatus
FROM   orders o
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (
         SELECT status,
                orderid,
                id,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY orderid ORDER BY id DESC ) AS rn
         FROM   order_unload
       ) ou
       ON ( o.orderid = ou.OrderID AND ou.rn = 1 )
WHERE  ProjectID = 141
ORDER BY ou.Id DESC;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b09354ba5df7bbd677b7a333a88c1c9e)*